# How to publish Json using rabbitmqadmin command

Tags: json, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl, rabbitmqadmin

I want to publish Json message using rabbitmqadmin command line. How can we do that as i was reading we can send only string message in payload like below
rabbitmqadmin publish exchange=default routing_key=test payload="hello, world".

But I wanted to send something like this:
rabbitmqadmin publish exchange=default routing_key=test payload=file.json

How can we do this in command line?

Answer (score 3):

this may depend on the library you're using at the other end, but to get the msg processed correctly (it was a string otherwise), I needed more:

```
./rabbitmqadmin publish exchange=foo routing_key=foo.bar.baz \
    properties='{"content_type":"application/json"}' \
    payload='{}' payload_encoding='string'
```

Note `content_type` with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an "API" but you can do it in this way:

```
python rabbitmqadmin publish \
       exchange=amq.default routing_key=test \
       payload="$(cat myjson.json)"
```

I tried it:

```
➜  bash python rabbitmqadmin publish \ 
        exchange=amq.default routing_key=test \
        payload="$(cat myjson.json)"

   Message published
```

Comment: It's strange that reading payload from file isn't supported. I noticed that if payload json is large the command reports the error: /usr/bin/rabbitmqadmin: Argument list too long